# Upgraded (from 23.04) to Ubuntu 23.10 - no App Center, no firmware flashing tool

Tags: 23.10, app-center

New software has been introduced on Ubuntu 23.10: a new Flutter-based App Center and a Firmware Updater tool, as can be read in [Ubuntu Desktop 23.10: Mantic Minotaur deep dive](https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-desktop-23-10-mantic-minotaur-deep-dive).

However, after upgrading from Ubuntu 23.04 to 23.10, I can't find either of these tools.

How can I get them?

Comment: To those who downvoted: Please reconsider, and perhaps remove downvotes - this is a legitimate question. Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I see this as well. Here's how to fix this.

```
snap-store --quit
sudo snap refresh snap-store --channel=latest/stable/ubuntu-23.10
```

If despite the `snap-store --quit` this tells you that it cannot do so, because it has running apps, something along the lines of

```
error: cannot refresh "snap-store": snap "snap-store" has running apps (ubuntu-software), pids:
       3071
```

`kill -9 3071` or whatever PID is being shown, then once more

```
sudo snap refresh snap-store --channel=latest/stable/ubuntu-23.10
```

That brought the App Center in for me.

On to firmware-updater. On my 23.04->23.10 it failed during do-release-upgrade.

This was easily remedied by just running that install once more once 23.10 was installed and had rebooted:

```
sudo snap install firmware-updater
```

Lastly, if you're keen, you can `snap list --all` and then `sudo snap remove SNAP --revision=REVISION` for each disabled snap.

Comment: Thank you - this worked perfectly. I wonder how many other things are different between new-as-intended intended, and upgraded systems. This is an issue that I hope future versions of the upgrade process will handle better.

Comment: System Monitor is another application that is not upgraded. It is still the old one.

Comment: From 23.10 fresh installation I got App Center icon showing only empty white page. After trying to update  and refresh snap I received icon of old Ubuntu Software showing available new packages. I placed this old icon into my dock and removed App Center icon from the dock to Applications. Now I wait for update re App Center.

Comment: I would recommend `snap-store --quit` instead of `kill -9`.  Let it exit cleanly, also no need to look up PID numbers.

Comment: Isn't `plasma-systemmonitor` for Kubuntu?

Comment: I am not quite sure tbh, but yes that makes sense. If it's not that, what would the "new system monitor" be? Just a misunderstanding?