# App Center & Firmware Updater do not launch

Tags: software-center, app-center

[image: Ubuntu App Center & Firmware Updater]

Hello, I've been using Ubuntu for a week now and I'm getting used to it day by day, and most issues I've faced, I was able to fix through research, except for this one.

All I find are references to either GNOME-Software which is a different app than Ubuntu's App Center and for the Firmware Updater I find references to "fwupd" which seems to be the older version of the current app Ubuntu uses.

Any help on how to fix this or re-install these 2 apps would be appreciated.

I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 23.10

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgraded (from 23.04) to Ubuntu 23.10 - no App Center, no firmware flashing tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488852/upgraded-from-23-04-to-ubuntu-23-10-no-app-center-no-firmware-flashing-tool)

Comment: I have the same problem with app center not launching.  App center was not added during the 23.10 upgrade, so I added it manually.  When I launch app center, it never launches.  There are no messages to the screen.