# following the installation of Ubuntu 23.10 on PI4 Raspberry

Tags: snap, 23.10, snap-store

I do not have a normal graphical operation with the application manager, the big A,it ended up disappearing completely, how could I reinstall or repair it? thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgraded (from 23.04) to Ubuntu 23.10 - no App Center, no firmware flashing tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488852/upgraded-from-23-04-to-ubuntu-23-10-no-app-center-no-firmware-flashing-tool)